# Cygnus subscription ngsi_version=2 not implemented

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I install the followin docker image of cygnus [this](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_docker/index.html). And when i try to make a subscription like the tutorial [example](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/management_interface_v1/index.html#section5.1) i got the following error:

```
POST /v1/subscriptions&ngsi_version=2 not implemented
```

This is my POST request:

```
{
"subscription":{
    "description": "One subscription to rule them all",
    "subject": {
        "entities": [
            {
                "idPattern": ".*",
                "type": "Room"
            }
        ],
        "condition": {
            "attrs": [
                "temperature"
            ],
            "expression": {
                  "q": "temperature>40"
            }
        }
    },
    "notification": {
        "http": {
            "url": "http://localhost:5050"
        },
        "attrs": [
            "temperature",
            "humidity"
        ]
    },
    "duration": "P1M",
    "throttling": 5
},
"endpoint":{
    "host":"151.80.41.166",
    "port":"50001",
    "ssl":"false",
    "xauthtoken":"QsENv67AJj7blC2qJ0YvfSc5hMWYrs"
 }
}
```

How i can enable the ngsi_version 2?